# IE not loading properly only the first time

Tags: php, css, html, internet-explorer

I have an application that works perfectly in Chrome,Firefox and Safari, but when I load it on IE happens a strange thing: all the page is loaded on the left side and after one or two refresh it loads properly.

Here are two descriptive images:

[image: First time IE loads the page]

And the second time (after one or more refresh) IE loads it like this:

[image: Second time]

Does anyone know why is IE having this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any javascript executed which: add/removes css classes, set's style properties, etc.?

Comment: Please can you provide code that allows us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: There is a javascript that calls an ajax function to delete an element if a button is clicked. The code is: echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   function deletePublication(id){
    $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'delete_element.php',    
     data:{type:'publication',id:id},        
     success:  function (response) {        
      location.reload();
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      location.reload;
     }
    });
   }        
   </script>";

Comment: I detected something, there is a file 'functions.php' that is causing some javascript problem. If I delete this file, the page loads properly (with the previsible errors of not finding some functions).  If i found the problem I post it, so other people with the same issue can solve it too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was quite simple.

I was calling my 'functions.php' as the very first code line (even before `<!DOCTYPE html`...). This file includes some javascripts function that CAN'T be loaded before `<!DOCTYPE html` (better between `<head></head>` tags).

Once I placed them between `<head>` tags the page is loading properly.

Thank you for the hints.